# Bitsadmin not recognizing if-modified-since header

Tags: file, http, powershell, file-transfer

I am trying to make a request with the header, if-modified-since but bitsadmin keeps giving me a transient error when I make this request

```
>bitsadmin /createjob myjob
>bitsadmin /setcustomheaders myjob "If-Modified-Since: Tue, 19 Jul 2015 21:50:00 GMT"
>bitsadmin /addfile myjob "http://localhost/myapi/getfile/fileid"
>bitsadmin /resume myjob
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Why does this lead to a transient error?

If bitsadmin is whats giving me issues, is there some other approach I can take to call my api with the header?

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: All it says is transient error. And it only occurs when I add the header.

Comment: Does `bitsadmin /info myjob /verbose` provide any meaningful output?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen "The parameter is incorrect". I don't understand what's wrong with my parameter

Comment: Might that be because you're using an invalid timestamp? July 19, 2015, was a Sunday, try with `bitsadmin /setcustomheaders myjob "If-Modified-Since: Sun, 19 Jul 2015 21:50:00 GMT"`

Comment: Agh, I meant to put 2016. Thanks, that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you provide a valid timestamp. In your example, the day of week is `Tue`sday and the date is `19 Jul 2015`, but that date was a `Sun`day.

If you are running bitsadmin in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) you can always use `Get-Date -Format r` or `$DateTime.ToString('r')` to produce a valid RFC822 timestamp:

```
bitsadmin /setcustomheaders myjob "If-Modified-Since: $(Get-Date -Day 19 -Month 7 -Year 2015 -Format 'r')"
```